# How to install editors when I am using texlive iso on fedora

Tags: texlive, linuxfedora

I am using `fedora` and I installed texlive from an iso file, not repositories. I then flagged out texlive from the `dnf` config file. However, when I try installing editors such as kile, gummi or lyx, I get the following error.

```
    Problem: package gummi-0.6.6-16.fc37.x86_64 requires texlive-latex, but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - package texlive-collection-latexrecommended-9:svn57862-59.fc37.noarch is filtered out by exclude filtering
  - package texlive-latex-9:20210325-52.fc37.noarch is filtered out by exclude filtering
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)
```

Is there a way of installing editors without pulling some texlive dependencies from the repositories?

Comment: I don't have a Fedora install at the moment, so I can't test it, but have you tried the [texlive-dummy](https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/fatka/texlive-dummy/) package from copr?

Comment: Ubuntu has a `--no-install-recommends` option for `apt`, fedora probably have something similar.

Comment: @frabjous that is the answer I needed. How do I put a tick to say it's correct?

Comment: I'll make it into a real answer so you can. I didn't want to make it an answer without (someone) testing it first, but I guess you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, it is possible to install the [texlive-dummy](https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/fatka/texlive-dummy/) package from the Fedora COPR (Cool Other Package Repository). This package satisfies the TeXlive dependencies required by packages such as kile, gummi, LyX, for dnf, without actually installing anything additional on your system.